# Can i use VS2012 to open older VS Version projecs without changing anything?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2005

Can i use VS2012 to open older VS Version projecs without changing anything?

I am just start with VS2012 and on college i always use VS2010, i have just start working with a new company and they use 2005 for most of the projects.

I want to know if there's a way that i can use VS2012 or VS2010 without changing anything so my (coworkers don't need to change anything)

NOTE: so far they dont use a TFS, but if they install one it must be 2010 cus is the one the other teams uses

Comment: what happened when you opened the 2005 solution with vs2012? if the projects/sln files are under source control you can see exactly what changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course: you just tell at the fist visual studio dialog box that you don't want to convert your VS 2010 project, and that's OK!